# MediaWiki - User Table

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to include a table with all registered users on a page in my MediaWiki but the only user list I can find is the special page "Active users list".
Is it possible to include this (or a similar list with e.g. the entered real name) on a wiki page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Special:ListUsers special page for this. It's a list of all users registered in your wiki.

You can include some special pages just like templates. So, to include the Special:ListUsers page on any wiki, you just need to paste the following wikitext code into the page where you want to show the user list:

```
{{Special:ListUsers}}
```

The limit for the list is 50 (iirc), so if you want to increase the length of the list, you can pass the `limit` parameter to the inclusion syntax:

```
{{Special:ListUsers|limit=100}}
```

However, I don't think that Special:ListUsers provides a way to show the real names of users, sorry.